# RADIUS Library not encrypting or encoding password string correctly

Tags: java, libraries, radius

I am currently working on a project involving direct authentication to a RADIUS server using Java and Python.

My Python implementation works fine, however I have tried two Java
libraries (TinyRADIUS and JRaD), and both exhibit the same behaviour:

When sending a PAP request all characters in the password after the first 16 appear to become either scrambled or half-UTF encoded, causing the server to fail authentication.

See below:

```
    JRaDclient rc = new JRaDclient();

    rc.setSecretKey("secrets");
    rc.setServer("127.0.0.1", 1812);
    rc.authenticate("testuser", "pass123LogeuCcoboJKidoDeVFesekSoluneCgaLttrjhrkrhn");
```

However, the resulting request on the server becomes this

```
rad_recv: Access-Request packet from host 127.0.0.1 port 1337, id=210, length=96
        User-Name = "testuser"
        User-Password = "pass123LogeuCcob\275\213?\353\210\352A1\333mP\266\253P[h\234zL\3021/\373\001\334\032\263\033BuKM\022\t\233\261r\301\3035
6\267\333+W'b\221"
```

Is this a simultaneous issue with the libraries or simply a configuration/version issue with Radius?

For reference, this is running on Java 8, with FreeRADIUS v2.1.12.

JRaD: https://github.com/punyal/JRaD
TinyRADIUS: http://tinyradius.sourceforge.net/

Comment: It seems that any password longer than 16 characters comes corrupted after that. We are currently debugging the sources of tinyradius v.1.0.2 - will update if there is something we can find.
Current suspicion is the fact that if the password is longer that 16 characters and not a multiple of 16 the password is padded (it's in the code) and then MD5'd, which probably FUBARs the original password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issues happens when passwords are longer than 16 characters - the password encoding pads the password and then encrypts it, which is incorrect.

We've included the source code in our project and replaced the pap password encoding and pap password decoding methods (in essence, encrypt the password before padding instead of encrypting with the padding).

Based on this: http://sourceforge.net/p/tinyradius/discussion/461293/thread/dcedb4ed/

This is the relevant code after the changes:

```
    /**
     * This method encodes the plaintext user password according to RFC 2865.
     * 
     * @param userPass
     *            the password to encrypt
     * @param sharedSecret
     *            shared secret
     * @return the byte array containing the encrypted password
     */
    private byte[] encodePapPassword(final byte[] userPass, byte[] sharedSecret) {
        // the password must be a multiple of 16 bytes and less than or equal
        // to 128 bytes. If it isn't a multiple of 16 bytes fill it out with zeroes
        // to make it a multiple of 16 bytes. If it is greater than 128 bytes
        // truncate it at 128.


    if (userPass == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("password is null");
    } else if (sharedSecret == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("shared secret is null");
    } else if (getAuthenticator() == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("authenticator is null");
    }

    byte[] userPassBytes = null;
    if (userPass.length > 128) {
        userPassBytes = new byte[128];
        System.arraycopy(userPass, 0, userPassBytes, 0, 128);
    } else {
        userPassBytes = userPass;
    }
    // declare the byte array to hold the final product
    byte[] encryptedPass = null;
    if (userPassBytes.length < 128) {
        if (userPassBytes.length % 16 == 0) {
            // tt is already a multiple of 16 bytes
            encryptedPass = new byte[userPassBytes.length];
        } else {
            // make it a multiple of 16 bytes
            encryptedPass = new byte[((userPassBytes.length / 16) * 16) + 16];
        }
    } else {
        // the encrypted password must be between 16 and 128 bytes
        encryptedPass = new byte[128];
    }
    // copy the userPass into the encrypted pass and then fill it out with zeroes
    System.arraycopy(userPassBytes, 0, encryptedPass, 0, userPassBytes.length);
    for (int i = userPassBytes.length; i < encryptedPass.length; i++) {
        encryptedPass[i] = 0;
    }
    // digest shared secret and authenticator
        MessageDigest md5 = getMd5Digest();

    md5.reset();
    byte[] bn = new byte[sharedSecret.length + getAuthenticator().length];
    for (int i = 0; i < bn.length; i++) {
        if (i < sharedSecret.length)
            bn[i] = sharedSecret[i];
        else
            bn[i] = getAuthenticator()[i - sharedSecret.length];
    }
    md5.update(bn);
    bn = md5.digest();
    // perform the XOR as specified by RFC 2865
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        encryptedPass[i] = (byte) (bn[i] ^ encryptedPass[i]);
    }
    if (encryptedPass.length > 16) {
        for (int i = 16; i < encryptedPass.length; i += 16) {
            md5.reset();
            md5.update(sharedSecret);
            // add the previous (encrypted) 16 bytes of the user password
            md5.update(encryptedPass, i - 16, 16);
            bn = md5.digest();
            // perform the XOR as specified by RFC 2865.
            for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
                encryptedPass[i + j] = (byte) (bn[j] ^ encryptedPass[i + j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return encryptedPass;
}

    /**
     * Decodes the passed encrypted password and returns the clear-text form.
     *
     * @param encryptedPass
     *            encrypted password
     * @param sharedSecret
     *            shared secret
     * @return decrypted password
     */
    private String decodePapPassword(byte[] encryptedPass, byte[] sharedSecret) throws RadiusException {
        if (encryptedPass == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("encrypted password is null");
        } else if (sharedSecret == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("shared secret is null");
        } else if (getAuthenticator() == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("authenticator is null");
        } else if (encryptedPass.length < 16) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid length of encrypted pass: " + encryptedPass.length);
        }

        // save original (encoded) encrypted pass
        byte[] encryptedPassOrig = encryptedPass.clone();
    //  MessageDigest md5;
        MessageDigest md5 = getMd5Digest();
        md5.reset();
        md5.update(sharedSecret);
        md5.update(getAuthenticator());
        byte bn[] = md5.digest();
        // perform the XOR as specified by RFC 2865
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            encryptedPass[i] = (byte) (bn[i] ^ encryptedPass[i]);
        }
        if (encryptedPass.length > 16) {
            for (int i = 16; i < encryptedPass.length; i += 16) {
                md5.reset();
                md5.update(sharedSecret);
                // now use original (encoded) pass to generate MD5
                md5.update(encryptedPassOrig, i - 16, 16);
                bn = md5.digest();
                // perform the XOR as specified by RFC 2865.
                for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
                    encryptedPass[i + j] = (byte) (bn[j] ^ encryptedPass[i + j]);
                }
            }
        }
        // remove trailing zeros
        int len = encryptedPass.length;
        while (len > 0 && encryptedPass[len - 1] == 0) {
            len--;
        }

        byte[] passtrunc = new byte[len];
        System.arraycopy(encryptedPass, 0, passtrunc, 0, len);
        // convert to string
        return RadiusUtil.getStringFromUtf8(passtrunc);
    }
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the response on that! I did wonder if it was something similar, since the password partially contained an OTP which pushed it over the 16 char limit I'm guessing that's what kicked it off.

Comment: Your code appears inconsistent with the note above _"in essence, encrypt the password before padding instead of encrypting with the padding"_ (where that note is itself contrary to the specification in the RFC).